# How GetBestRoute Function Works?

Tags: winapi, networking, network-interface

I wonder how Windows chooses a specific network interface to be the local endpoint rather than another.

For example if I have a Wireless NIC and an Ethernet NIC connected to the same LAN, and I want to estalish a TCP connection to another PC on that LAN, **based on what** one of these two interfaces will be used as the local endpoint?

From what I've read so far I learned that [GetBestInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getbestinterface) function uses [GetBestRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getbestroute) to determine the best interface for a destination endpoint, but I couldn't find **how it works**.

Some sources talk about routing tables, but again how the routing table chooses the local interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Routing uses the longest match to determine the best route, and in the event of a tie, there are other things, like metrics, that come into play.

Comment: From ReactOS: https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/master/dll/win32/iphlpapi/iphlpapi_main.c